# What happens when I delete backup folder?

Tags: backup

Commonly backup needs for stupidity. In Ubuntu when I run default Backups application it creates a new folder. If I accidentally delete this folder also(very stupid) then is it possible to recover my lost data?

Comment: @muru, then why the Ubuntu default backup application?

Comment: Because it's stupid to rely on a deleted file's contents still being available and not overwritten.